# Can not show data tokeninput when edit value

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-tokeninput

I tried to make the autocomplete data by jquery.tokeninput.js and insert into the database when it was saved, but now I will edit and display the data does not appear, whether the value of data can be displayed?

```
Views
<input type="text"  class='form-control' id="tokenfield" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#tokenfield").tokenInput("<?php echo base_url(); ?>form/prosedurkerja/get_prosedur", {
            classes: {
                tokenList: "form-control token-input-list-facebook",
                token: "token-input-token-facebook",
                tokenDelete: "token-input-delete-token-facebook",
                selectedToken: "token-input-selected-token-facebook",
                highlightedToken: "token-input-highlighted-token-facebook",
                dropdown: "token-input-dropdown-facebook",
                dropdownItem: "token-input-dropdown-item-facebook",
                dropdownItem2: "token-input-dropdown-item2-facebook",
                selectedDropdownItem: "token-input-selected-dropdown-item-facebook",
                inputToken: "token-input-input-token-facebook"
            }
        });
});
```

Controllers

```
function edit() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    if ($id == NULL) {
        redirect('myviews_1');
    }
    $get_id = $this->mymodel->get_name($id);
    $data['id'] = $get_id->id;
    $data['name'] = $get_id->name;  
    $data=array(
        'name' => $dt->name,
        'id'   => $id,');       
    $this->load->view('myviews_2');
}
```

Models

```
function get_name($id) {
    $d = $this->db->get_where('mytable', array('id' => $id))->row();
    return $d;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error in PHP or Javascript?

Comment: no error message in php or javascript, but the expected data does not appear when using `id = tokeninput`

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller data by this,

```
function edit() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    if ($id == NULL) {
        redirect('myviews_1');
    }
    $get_id = $this->mymodel->get_name($id);
    $data['id'] = $get_id->id;
    $data['name'] = $get_id->name;  
    $data=array(
        'name' => $dt->name,
        'id'   => $id);       
    $this->load->view('myviews_2',$data);
}
```

I hope this may help you.

Comment: yes thank you but the data does not appear on the input name